# TYPO3 extbase: Customize 1:1 relation query

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'd like modify an existing TYPO3 extension by adding extbase domain models while keeping the existing database structure.

There are two database tables: `location` and `person`, and they have no direct connection - the old code simply related them by their `pid` column. If you want the `location` for a `person`, you'd have to select the `location` that has the same `pid`.

Now I would like to be able to load the location from the person's domain model class, but extbase is not able to figure out how to load it automatically.

What do I have to do to override/customize extbase's relation loading behavior, so that I can access the `location` object via `$person.location`, while benefiting from extbase's automatic caching and eager loading?

(When implementing `getLocation()` in the Person class myself, extbase would not load the location automatically in the first SQL query. Also, I'd have to implementthe local caching myself, so that repeated accesses to `getLocation()` would not lead to duplicated database accesses.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the extension yourself, I would go for using https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/extender and add the additional property + getters.

Additionally you need to extend the TCA to let editors select the relation in the backend.

Comment: I can change the extension; it's own code. But my question was how can I override the extbase relation loading process without modifying the database structure?

Comment: Either Xclass \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper::mapSingleRow and modify $row[location] or update all records and set the location in the TCA correctly